# I want to know what kind of bike frame I have can you help me the serial number is djei 1 76488

Tags: identify-this-bike, bmx

It's a 24-inch BMX bike

Serial number djei 17648 8

[image]

Comment: You probably have a 24-inch BMX style bike.  (Or, actually, just a bike frame.)  Probably it's Chinese, but there's no way to tell without a metallurgical analysis or some such.

Comment: I always wonder why people want to know details on a generic bike. Even more so if it fits into a certain category merely by its look. This one is just BMX (frame). Nothing extra-ordinary!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why shouldn't I care what model/make/year my bicycle is?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/52060/why-shouldnt-i-care-what-model-make-year-my-bicycle-is)

Answer (score 3):

Three is no way to know what you have.  BMXs are generally very similar.

Serial numbers are not like VINs on a car, they are not catalogued together anywhere and they're not even guaranteed unique across a manufacturer.

Your best bet is to talk with whoever supplied the frame.  Ask them for info, but sellers may state its ValuableBrand when its not.

You appear to have a lot of bearings and parts, which is awesome and uncommon.  Simply paint it and reassemble, and enjoy the bike for what it is.   Just don't label it as something its not.  You can get custom decals made up for cheap, call it a "Jutorrey" and you're no less wrong than anyone else.

Answer (score -2):

It looks lile a kent or a mongoose most deffenetly a walmart
Bike

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site, are there any details in particular about the bike which help lead to this conclusion?

Comment: Welcome to Bicycles SE. We're looking for answers with [more detail](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer). Please consider expanding your answer to explain what leads you to believe that it is definitely a WalMart bike, and probably a Kent or Mongoose. Also, are you certain that it came from WalMart specifically? Or did you simply mean that it's from a big box store? A short, one-line answer like this is likely to get downvoted, flagged for moderator intervention, and possibly deleted.