# Hi what Brand is this fixed-gear bike?

Tags: identify-this-bike, fixed-gear

[image]

White frame  it looks like a road bicycle

Serial number is DJEI265384

Comment: https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/51913/i-want-to-know-what-kind-of-bike-frame-i-have-can-you-help-me-the-serial-number

Comment: The linked question here shares the same prefix in the serial number, but you've tagged this with [27-inch] which suggests an old road bike sized wheel.  Could you add decent photos of your bike, clear and well lit.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why shouldn't I care what model/make/year my bicycle is?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/52060/why-shouldnt-i-care-what-model-make-year-my-bicycle-is)

Comment: Bicycles don't carry VINumbers like motorized road vehicles do. There is no such database either.

Comment: The best chance of identifying a bicycle is to post good pictures of the whole frame and close up pictures of any distinctive features including any stickers / labels, drop outs, seat stay/seat tube joint, brake bridge etc. If you post pictures there are a few of us with a psychological disorder that causes us to look at hundreds of pictures of bicycles looking for a match. Just to set expectations, it is very difficult to identify frames. Tens of thousands of generic bicycles are manufactured in China every year. The same frame may have several different brands or model names.

Comment: @manuel please add a clear and well lit photo of the whole bike from the right hand side.    With that edited in, your question can be re-opened.

Comment: well i woud like to now

Comment: @Manuel great work thank you - that was sufficient to identify the bike by the one decal that is on straight :)

Answer (score 2):

Based on the downtube logo this is a "FIX-D" brand of fixed-gear bicycle.

These are low-spec bikes sold through Target and aliexpress.  The frame is Steel.

Someone has removed the front brake and brake lever, and the front wheel's QR lever is in a bad angle.  Can't comment on the rear of the bike.  The saddle on yours is from a Diamondback as well.

The front tyre has been changed at some time, and its possible the front wheel is different from stock too.

The left hand pedal is busted in half - that's not safe to ride and needs to be replaced.  Generally you have to buy pedals in pairs, check elsewhere on this site for how to fit and the pitfalls/gotchas.

I removed the 27-inch tag because this bike has 700c wheels, which are 622mm.

[image]

Source: https://www.propertyroom.com/l/magna-fixd-road-bike/10178232

Comment: Good eye! Great find.